# Getting multiple-value parameter passed via a jQuery ajax POST, in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

In another question, the following code was offered as a way to send a list of checkboxes via ajax POST:

```
var data = { 'user_ids[]' : []};
$(":checked").each(function() {
  data['user_ids[]'].push($(this).val());
});
$.post("ajax.php", data);
```

I have a JSP page in which I would like to parse the value data in `data`. What format would the data be in (i.e. string or array)?  How can I parse it?

Thanks!

Comment: In PHP, `$_POST['user_ids']` would be an array.  Not sure how JSP handles this.

Comment: @Rocket: PHP has soms bizzare features which aren't part of standard HTML spec at all. When you suffix the parameter name with `[]`, it automagically becomes an array in PHP when you get it just by the name, because there's no other way to obtain multiple values by name. This is nowhere specified in HTML spec, let alone the HTTP spec. JSP/Servlet does it more elegantly.

Answer (score 1):

- you don't need `[]`
- you can obtain the values by `request.getParameterValues("user_ids")`